# jquery .each loop inside td tag

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to iterate array in the same td tag
I have tried doing this:

```
$.each(data, function(index, val){                       
        row.append($("<td>" + val.attr_value; + "</td>"));
        });
```

but it is printing two `td` tags as its in loop, but I need to iterate and print values in single `td` tag

Comment: What do you mean? Your question isn't clear at all.

Comment: Why would you drop jQuery into a table cell?

Comment: I need to put .each loop inside the <td> tag

Comment: @j08691 thats just for reference

Comment: Do you want to generate some <TD> using a jquery loop?

Comment: I have this `row.append($("<td>" + *** + "</td>"));`  instead of *** i need .each loop to iterate array

Comment: What you are saying doesn't make any sense.  Tell us exactly what your desired result is and maybe we can help you from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want everything from the `data` array inside a single `<td>` you need to move the creation of the `td` outside your loop, and let the loop simply build your content as a string. Something like this:

```
var content = "";
$.each(data, function(index, val){
  content += val.attr_value + " ";
});
row.append($("<td>" + content + "</td>"));
```

Answer (score 1):

First generate data in your iteration block:

```
$.each(data, function(index, val){                       
    //Concatenate data here
    });
```

Then insert the generated `data` inside the TD and append it to what you want:

```
row.append($("<td>" + data ));
```

Comment: @JKLM well this is not a fully complete example. Did you understand the idea?

Comment: @JKLM I wrote an answer with a more complete example. Also this example here is not very clear because of the re-use of the `data` variable.

Answer (score 1):

here is an example how to add `td` with values programmatically

```js
let data = [1, 2]
let $td = ''
$.each(data, function(index, val) {      
  $td += '<td>' + val + '</td>'   
})

$('table tbody tr').append($td)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
          <th>first column</th>
          <th>second column</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>  
    <tbody>
        <tr></tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```